# Java Numbers not showing up in Text Field, I want to be read in as a String

Tags: java, swing

I am new to Java. I wrote a similar app that puts text into a JTextField when I click a button, the text associated with the button would show up in the JTextField. Now I am doing it will numbers (attempting to read a String) but when I click the button, nothing is showing up. I know it is probably something small I am missing. If you can help I would really appreciate it! :)

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class SimpleButtons_Wallace extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    private JButton button0;
    private JButton button1;
    private JButton button2;
    private JButton button3;
    private JTextField Textfield;
    public SimpleButtons_Wallace() {
        GridLayout experimentLayout = new GridLayout(0, 2);
        JPanel MiniME = new JPanel();
        button0 = new JButton("zero");
        button0.addActionListener(this);
        button1 = new JButton("1");
        button1.addActionListener(this);
        button2 = new JButton("2");
        button2.addActionListener(this);
        button3 = new JButton("3");
        button3.addActionListener(this);
        Textfield = new JTextField(10);
        Textfield.addActionListener(this);
        MiniME.setLayout(experimentLayout);
        add(MiniME);
        MiniME.add(button0);
        MiniME.add(button1);
        MiniME.add(button2);
        MiniME.add(button3);
        MiniME.add(Textfield);
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JButton b = (JButton) e.getSource();
        Textfield.setText(b.getText());
    }
}
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.*;
public class GuiMain_Wallace extends JFrame {
    public GuiMain_Wallace() {
        getContentPane().add(new SimpleButtons_Wallace());
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        GuiMain_Wallace aframe = new GuiMain_Wallace();
        aframe.setSize(225, 230);
        aframe.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

//Here are the two classes I attempted you use. Is there anything I can do to //make the JTextField to be populated.

Comment: Variable names should NOT start with an upper case character. Don't forget to "accept" answer by clicking on the check mark beside the answer so people know the problem has bees solved. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33883073/java-jpanel-is-not-showing-up

Answer (score 1):

> but when I click the button, nothing is showing up.

The problem is that you are attempting to manage the size of the frame (you mad the frame size too small so the text of the text field is truncated). Don't do that. Use the pack() method so the components can be displayed at their preferred sizes:

```
//aframe.setSize(225, 230);
aframe.pack();
```

It is always a good idea to create a JTextField with a number. This number is used for the text field to determine its preferred size. In your case you specified 10, which means it will display a minimum of 10 characters before you need to scroll the text.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're limiting the Textfield with JTextField(10).

Remove the limit:

```
Textfield = new JTextField();
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank You! I really appreciate it! Have a good one! :)

Comment: No problem, same to you also ^.^

Comment: @B.Wallace, No, this is not the problem. The problem is that you are attempting to manage the size of the frame. This is resulting in the first character of the text field being truncated. Just manually resize the frame and you will see the complete text. Don't hardcode a random size. Swing was designed to be used with layout managers, so use the pack() method on the frame so the frame can do its job.